# Navigate between Changes in source control panel in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate between changed files in the Source Control view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Use the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys.